# Why some of the css styling is not showing when i link the css to an html?

Tags: html, css, styling

**Why not all my styling is applied?**

---

If all styling is shown, my webpage should be in pink.
Could anyone give me a solution, please?
The above are my css stylesheet and html

Forgive me if I ask something stupid, I'm just a beginner.

---

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Information literacy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="sidenav">
      <p style="font-size:30px;color:#ffffff;font-family: 'Palette Mosaic'">Topics</p>
      <a href=""> Careers and life planning</a>
      <hr>
      <a href=""> Information Literacy</a>
      <hr>
      <a href=""> Reference</a>
    <hr>
    </div>

  <div class="main">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <h2> This is MY Webpage</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

**this is the css stylesheet**
all colors, background-color and the font-family is not changed. But the font-size can be changed.

Why?

```css
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Palette+Mosaic&display=swap');
  
  body {
    background-color: #ffbbbb;
    font-family: 'Palette Mosaic', Copperplate;
    min-height: 150vh;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  a {
    font-family: Copperplate;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
 
 .sidenav {
  height: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  padding: 15px;
}
.main{
  margin-left: 220px;
}
  h1{
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    }
 
</style>
```

Comment: It work fine for me. I think you should embed style to html file, if it works f the error maybe in your <link> tag

Comment: remove the <style></style> tags from the css file, otherwise there is no issue with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `<style> </style>` tags in your style.css file. Those are only for writing css styles directly into the .html file.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Palette+Mosaic&display=swap');
  
  body {
    background-color: #ffbbbb;
    font-family: 'Palette Mosaic', Copperplate;
    min-height: 150vh;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  a {
    font-family: Copperplate;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
 
 .sidenav {
  height: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  padding: 15px;
}
.main{
  margin-left: 220px;
}
  h1{
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Information literacy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="sidenav">
      <p style="font-size:30px;color:#ffffff;font-family: 'Palette Mosaic'">Topics</p>
      <a href=""> Careers and life planning</a>
      <hr>
      <a href=""> Information Literacy</a>
      <hr>
      <a href=""> Reference</a>
    <hr>
    </div>

  <div class="main">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <h2> This is MY Webpage</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've removed <style></style> in css stylesheet and it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Only remove style tag and run your code it will work.